# Why does XPath select nodes outside of context node?

Tags: html, node.js, xml, xpath

I'm using XPath with Node.js and I have the following HTML document, where I want to select all article nodes and then in a second step all divs with class `"abc"`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello0!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello1!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello2!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello3!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello4!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello5!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello6!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello7!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello8!</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>123456</div>
        <div class="abc">Hello9!</div>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

I used following code to select the nodes:

```
var xpath = require('xpath');
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

let parser: DOMParser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString("HTML-document","text/xml");
let nodes: Node[] = xpath.select("//article", doc);
console.log("NODES: ", nodes.length);
let divs: Node[] = xpath.select("//div[@class='abc']", nodes[0]);
console.log("DIVS: ", divs.length);
```

My problem is, when checking the two console-logs, the first one says `"NODES: 10"`.

So far, I have ten article nodes. However, when I select again on the first of the ten article nodes, the console says `"DIVS: 10"`. So XPath selected all 10 divs out of one article, where I expected just one `div`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You should note that `//` means search wherever on the page starting from root element while `.//` means search wherever on the page starting from the current node. So if you want to start search from already found `article` element you need to replace

```
"//div[@class='abc']"
```

with

```
".//div[@class='abc']"
```

or

```
"./div[@class='abc']"
```

as `div` is the direct child of `article`

Answer (score 2):

Andersson has already provided the [correct direct answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42400089/290085) (+1), but here is just another option: You can combine your two XPaths into one: This XPath,

```
//article[0]/div[@class='abc']
```

will select the same `div` element as your two step process does.

You can even be more elaborate at any step in the path.  This XPath will select the `div` elements with `@class='abc'` within `article` elements with a `div` child whose string value is `123456`:

```
//article[div='123456']/div[@class='abc']
```

For the particular XML document shown, the predicate on `article` selects all `articles`, but this possibility for refinement exists in general.