# How to use PHP DOMXPath to find a child by type and data-attribute?

Tags: php, domxpath

I thought it would be fairly simple but could not make it work.

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
        
    <div data-nr="1" data-title="Calculate 15 - 11">
        <div class="basiccalc">
            <p class="subtractline">15 - 11 = </p>
            <p class="resultline">
                <input type="hidden" data-check="4">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div data-nr="2" data-title="Calculate 20 - 13">
        <div class="basiccalc">
            <p class="subtractline">20 - 13 = </p>
            <p class="resultline">
                <input type="hidden" data-check="7">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I try to use DOMXPath to go over the two `div`s and get the text within the `data-check` attribute of the `input` element.

I tried the following (note, I need to focus on the question title with the first query):

```
$q_titles = $finder->query('//div/@data-title');

foreach($q_titles as $q)
{
    $qtitle = $q->nodeValue;
                
    $nr = $q->parentNode->getAttribute('data-nr');
    
    $children = $q->parentNode->childNodes;

    foreach($children as $c)
    {
        $inputnode = $finder->query('//input/@data-check', $c);
        if(!empty($inputnode[0]))
        {
            // text of data-check attribute
            $solution = $inputnode[0]->parentNode->getAttribute('data-check');
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns `4` and `4` instead of `4` and `7`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: There may be neater ways of solving this, but I think your current issue can be solved by adding a `.` to the last XPath `'.//input/@data-check'` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399404/why-does-xpath-select-nodes-outside-of-context-node).

Comment: It works! Wow, a dot was the solution for one hour of trying to get this code working.  Thanks a lot. 

Comment: How can I reward you with reputation points?

Comment: Don't worry - just glad to be able to help :)